# Why does latexml not recognize "\appendixpage" from the "appendix" package?

Tags: latexml

Here is an error from latexml (installed with `brew install latexml` on OS X):

```
$ latexml foo.tex
latexml (LaTeXML version 0.8.5)
processing started Sun Aug 29 10:28:25 2021

(Digesting TeX foo...
(Loading /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.5/libexec/lib/perl5/LaTeXML/Package/TeX.pool.ltxml...
(Loading /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.5/libexec/lib/perl5/LaTeXML/Package/eTeX.pool.ltxml... 0.00 sec)
(Loading /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.5/libexec/lib/perl5/LaTeXML/Package/pdfTeX.pool.ltxml... 0.00 sec) 0.14 sec)
(Processing content a_dir/foo.tex...
(Loading /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.5/libexec/lib/perl5/LaTeXML/Package/LaTeX.pool.ltxml...
(Loading /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.5/libexec/lib/perl5/LaTeXML/Package/textcomp.sty.ltxml... 0.01 sec) 0.18 sec)
(Loading /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.5/libexec/lib/perl5/LaTeXML/Package/book.cls.ltxml... 0.01 sec)
(Loading /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.5/libexec/lib/perl5/LaTeXML/Package/appendix.sty.ltxml... 0.00 sec)
Error:undefined:\appendixpage The token T_CS[\appendixpage] is not defined.
    at foo.tex; line 9 col 0 - line 9 col 13
    Defining it now as <ltx:ERROR/>
    Next token is T_CS[\addappheadtotoc]
    In Core::Gullet[@0x7ffe5bbebc30] a_dir/foo.tex; from line 10 col 0 to line 10 col 16
     <= Core::Stomach[@0x7ffe5c0d9028] <= ...

Error:undefined:\addappheadtotoc The token T_CS[\addappheadtotoc] is not defined.
    at foo.tex; line 10 col 0 - line 10 col 16
    Defining it now as <ltx:ERROR/>
    Next token is T_CS[\par]
    In Core::Gullet[@0x7ffe5bbebc30] a_dir/foo.tex; from line 11 col 0 to line 11 col 1
     <= Core::Stomach[@0x7ffe5c0d9028] <= ...
 0.24 sec) 0.38 sec)
(Building...
(Loading compiled schema /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.5/libexec/lib/perl5/LaTeXML/resources/RelaxNG/LaTeXML.model... 0.01 sec). 0.05 sec)
(Rewriting... 0.00 sec)
(Finalizing... 0.00 sec)
Conversion complete: 2 errors; 2 undefined macros[\appendixpage, \addappheadtotoc].
```

Here is the latex:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc

\appendix
\chapter[Chapter]{Chapter}
\chaptermark{Chaptermark}

Here's a chapter.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure, that's just a cut and paste error. I changed the "include" to an "input" above (and in the original file). This is not the same question. This question is about `appendixpage`.

Comment: I am not using \include. That was a cut-and-paste error.

Comment: I made a single reproducible test case, and pasted the actual error messages.

Comment: Thanks I get same error:-) you could ask on latexml github for the appendix package support to be extended, or use `\part*{Appendix}` which seems to be more or less the same

Comment: The original `appendix` package from CTAN defines the `\appendixpage` macro. I have no ide what might be on latexml github or why it should differ from the CTAN version.

Comment: @PeterWilson LaTeXML uses Perl to convert tex to xml.  Sometimes they use the CTAN version of a style file, and sometimes they write their own conversion.  It appears they wrote their own conversion for the `appendix` package, but missed this command.

Answer (score 3):

The ("incompletely implemented") code for that package is at https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML/blob/master/lib/LaTeXML/Package/appendix.sty.ltxml, and does not include the `\appendixpage` command (it's commented out at line 28).  That explains why you get the error.  To fix the error, you could approximate it as David Carlisle suggested: `\providecommand{\appendixpage}{\part*{\appendixname}}`.  You could also try copying definitions from the package, but there are several definitions that you'd need to trace through.

Comment: Thanks for the code ref. That code seems to define `\appendices`. I wonder if that is a command I could use (that would also work outside of latexml).

Comment: You can also `\usepackage{latexml}` to access the conditional `\iflatexml...\else...\fi`.